# Crear un código QR con geolocalización

Tags: geolocalización, qrcode, qr

Estamos creando un dispositivo para el cuidado de mascotas. La idea es un código QR conteniendo toda la info de la mascota para que en caso de extravío se puedan comunicar con el propietario de la misma. Hasta aquí fácil... pero la idea es hacer en caso de robo de la mascota que si alguien lee el código, poder saber desde que ubicación fue leído. Estamos realizando la pagina en wordpress y he visto un par de plugins pero no logro que me de la analítica de lectura... espero puedan ayudar a esta causa noble. Lamentablemente no sabemos mucho (diría nada) de programación) pero necesitamos este servicio... gracias !!!!

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y leas [ask]

Comment: Un código QR no puede tener geolocalización, un código QR tiene datos. Normalmente (pero no de forma obligatoria) esos datos pueden ser un enlace a un sitio web, este sitio web puede tener geolocalización, pero el usuario que visita el sitio debe dar los permisos necesarios para ello. Por otro lado y de forma respetuosa te comento que este sitio es para programadores, si tu no sabes programación este no el sitio adecuado para ti.